# Ordery by dynamic relations

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a product table.  A sku table which has a many to one in relation to product.  An options table, that has a many to one in relation to product, through a relation table, and a many to one to sku via a relation table. An option type table, that has a one to many to option.  Example schema

EX

```
Product
ID   Name
1    dress

ProductOptionRelation
productID optionID displayOrder
1         1        1
1         2        1

Option
ID    Type Name
1     1    Red
2     1    Blue
3     2    0
4     2    2
5     2    4

OptionType
ID  name  displayOrder
1   color 1
2   size  2

Sku
ID productID
1  1
2  1
3  1
4  1
5  1

SkuOptionRelation
skuID OptionID
1     1
1     3
2     1
2     4
3     1
3     5
4     2
4     3
5     2
5     5
```

How can I join this all together so my output would be like

```
skuID  option
1      red
1      0
2      red
2      2
3      red
3      4
4      blue
4      0
5      blue
5      4
```

Assuming all the IDs are actually uuids and cant be used for sorting.  As well as there may be any number of options for a product as well as not all option combinations for a product need to exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT s.skuID, o.Name
FROM SkuOptionRelation s
INNER JOIN [Option] o ON o.ID = s.OptionID 
INNER JOIN OptionType ot ON ot.ID = o.Type
order by s.skuid, ot.DisplayOrder
```

Result:

```
skuID       Name
----------- ----------------
1           Red
1           0
2           Red
2           2
3           Red
3           4
4           Blue
4           0
5           Blue
5           4

(10 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: this would fail to sort correctly.  you are assuming that the sku ID has an intrinsic value.  Its a uuid and can't be used for sorting.

Comment: @xxxpigeonxxx your question is not clear, plus in your example you used int as sku (1,2,3,4,5). I don't understand what value do you want to sort by

Comment: I specified "Assuming all the IDs are actually uuids and cant be used for sorting"  Would it really have made any difference if I had used values like '7C81D22B-503C-4DA0-B4F8-2A9C3B3EC2D2', it would only draw attention to long values rather than the schema.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something it seems your desired output has nothing to do with the product. And merely an sku with options, which would be...

```
select so.skuID, o.name
from SkuOptionRelation so
join Option o on so.OptionID = o.ID
```

If sorting is the issue and it comes from the product table then that would be ...

```
select so.skuID, o.name
from SkuOptionRelation so
join Option o on so.OptionID = o.ID
join sku s on so.skuID = s.ID
join ProductOptionRelation po on po.productID = s.productID and so.optionID = po.optionID
order by s.ID, po.displayOrder
```

Just saw the other answer which suggests type order matters also. So now we have ...

```
select so.skuID, o.name
from SkuOptionRelation so
join Option o on so.OptionID = o.ID
join OptionType ot on o.type = ot.ID
join sku s on so.skuID = s.ID
join ProductOptionRelation po on po.productID = s.productID and so.optionID = po.optionID
order by s.ID, ot.displayOrder, po.displayOrder
```